# Asserting that caller holds mutex

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, mutex, assert

I was asked today why there's no function `pthread_mutex_assert_locked` that could be used (at least with error-checking mutexes) to assert that the caller holds a particular mutex. Subsequent discussion turned up the possibility to implement the assertion as:

```
assert(pthread_mutex_lock(m)==EDEADLK);
```

for error-checking mutexes. This will reliably trigger an assertion failure if the mutex is unlocked when it's reached, or if another thread has it locked and unlocks it, but in actual deadlock scenarios where the (other) thread that holds the mutex will not make forward progress until the thread making the assertion does, it will deadlock.

Is this the best we can do with the existing pthread mutex API? Is there a better way to assert mutex ownership that reliably triggers not subject to deadlock?

Comment: Do you know, or can you control, what type of mutexes are in use, or do you have to work with whatever mutex you are given?  Working with a generic mutex where you don't know the type will be tricky.  See [`pthread_mutex_lock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) (and
[`pthread_mutex_init()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html)) for more information.

Comment: I think it's fair to assume this is at best only possible for errorchecking and maybe (unlikely) recursive mutexes. Normal type mutexes are specifically designed so that they can optimize out the need to know their owner. I think it's also fair to assume the code knows which type of mutex it's using.

Comment: Hmm.. `assert(pthread_mutex_trylock(m)==EDEADLK);`? No, I think it would require something like `pthread_mutex_owned()` to be provided by the pthreads library. That said, if I needed the facility, I'd use my own mutex structure containing a `pthread_mutex_t` and a `pthread_t`, and the requisite handling functions, so I can implement the owner check myself.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: That's a good point that you can do it with some sort of wrapping, but I was thinking of approaches that would be minimally invasive and wouldn't require changing function signatures.